# mysql - SELECT FROM .. TO

Tags: mysql, select, rows

Is it possible in MySQL to select rows for a certain range of items?

For example when I want to select all items in where the first letter of the NAME is between the B and T, alphabetically.
I know I can make this is PHP aswell, but it would save me a bit of time if this is possible in MySQL...

Is it possible, and if so, how?

The ideal situation would be something like this:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM paths FROM name=name1 TO name=name6"; //which would select name1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `BETWEEN` will basically get you there, but you need to use one letter past where you want to end. Experiment until you get the result you desire.

```
SELECT * FROM paths WHERE UPPER(name) BETWEEN 'B' AND 'U';
```

The idea here is that everything beginning with a 'T' will sort alphabetically before anything beginning with a 'U'. You need to convert it to upper-case via `UPPER()` so you don't run up against potential collation problems.

So your results could be like:

```
B,
Bill
Bob
Jane
Tommy
Travis
```

But `Uwe` (He's German) would be excluded.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks! That is exactly what I'm looking for! Can this also be done with partial matches, for example when the names are, BAA, BBB, CDA, CEF, PFE, etc?

Comment: @laarsk Partial matches are subject to the same rules, so yes it should work. In other words, as long as it starts with something before `U`, it would be included.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! [Still have to wait 4 minutes to mark this as the answer...]

Comment: Using a function on name will kill any chance of using an index though. Better to use `where (name between 'B' and 'U' or name between 'b' and 'u')` if you're using a case-sensitive collation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BETWEEN` like:

```
SELECT * FROM paths WHERE name BETWEEN 'B' AND 'U'
```

Comment: no, params 2 should be 'name7', or something, name6 would not be caught with between (hence other folks use of 'U' for the end get get 'T's